# ng-model is not getting updated properly (angular-ui-tinymce)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-tinymce

I am trying to insert a DOM node on a custom button click. but the model associated with the textarea is not getting updated.

I have created a plunker to demonstrate the issue.

```
[https://plnkr.co/edit/Qe3COw][1]
```

Try clicking the 'My Button' more than once. from the second click, the model is not getting updated.

Thanks in advance, i hope the question is understandable

Answer (score 1):

Using the below function solved the issue for me.

```
editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, a);
```

Plunker:

```
https://plnkr.co/edit/vHF3sS?p=preview
```